# Generar un código (serial) de usuario de datos en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

necesito generar un serial de inscripción para cada usuario que se registre a través de php, mysql y laravel 8, con esta forma:

año-país-sector-numeroIncrementable

ejemplo: 2022-001-51-1000

entonces yo había realizado un script que me funciona pero, me dijeron que habría una mejor forma pero no lo logro.

este es mi código:

```
 $pais = $request->pais;
 $año = date('Y');
 $sector_economico= '00'.$request->sector_economico;

        if($cod_anterior = Inscripcion::latest('cod_cliente')->first()){
            $num = substr($cod_anterior->cod_cliente, 11);
        }else{
            $num = 10001;
        }
        $num = $num + 1;
        $cod_nuevo=$año.'-'.$pais.'-'.$sector_economico.'-'.$num;
```

el codigo anterior me funciona solucitando el ultimo serial registrado en la BD, y el incrementable debe iniciar en 10000, entonces no se si existirá una mejor forma de hacerlo.

de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿`latest('cod_cliente')` busca el valor máximo de esa columna en una tabla? Pregunto porque no conozco laravel

Comment: hola si, te busca el ultimo valor insertado en una columna de una tabla en la base  de datos

Comment: Hm, pues es que esa aproximación tiene problemas con accesos concurrentes (dos peticiones simultáneas pueden obtener el mismo valor). Pero en MySQL no hay secuencias hasta donde recuerdo :S